# Make parent window visible

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, styles

I am using Silverlight.
I have a Parent window with an Expander and some buttons etc..

One button calls a Child Window. I am interested in the visual content of the ParentWindow while the ChildWindow is prompted.

I've managed to make the content of the Expander visible using CustomTemplate. I've also set the OverlayBrush to "Transparent" and the OverlayOpacity to 0. 
Still, when the ChildWindow is opened the whole Parent window becomes transparent'ish and one can't fully understand the information there.

I need it to remain as before the ChildWindow appeared.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: @Sheridan That's not what he's asking. There's a difference between "active" and "visible". "Leave active" means that the parent window retains focus, while the child window opens without focus. This question is saying that the parent window becomes translucent and hard to read, and he wants the opacity to remain the same; I think it's safe to infer from the question that he *does* want the child window to become active when it opens.

Comment: True, i did solve it using 2 things: Set child overlayBrush to transparent and opacity to 0 and by using Application.Current.RootVisual.SetValue (Control.IsEnabledProperty, true) just after showing the child window. This does not really make the root active, the buttons on the parent window are not clickable. Still it is visible as though it would be active..  Anyway, thank you for the support!

Comment: All the more reason to reopen this question--so that the OP can post his solution as an answer...which you can see is not at all the same as the answer to the linked question--because it's not the same question--and it sounds like information that would be useful to others in the future.